# Covering map of Klein Bottle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

It is well known that plane is universal cover of Torus and Klein Bottle. If we consider the map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$, defined as $\phi(x,y)=(e^{2i\pi x},e^{2i\pi y})$, then $\phi$ becomes covering map for Torus.

> In a similar manner how we can find a covering map for Klein bottle.

I have seen questions like this [The double cover of Klein bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183086/the-double-cover-of-klein-bottle?rq=1) , but did not find the appropriate thing. Please help me thanking you.

Comment: Well, first of all you need to decide what your Klein bottle is. Like how $S^1\times S^1$ is your torus. Only after that can we start defining functions from the plane to the Klein bottle. In the post you linked, the answers use the plane (or a region of the plane) with points identified. And in that respect, those answers are _exactly_ what you're after. But if you have a different representation of the Klein bottle in mind, then tell us what it is, and we will be able to help you.

Comment: @Arthur,  Klein bottle ishomeomorphic to $D^2\times S^1$.

Comment: $D^2$? As in the unit disc?

Comment: @Arthur Yes sir it is unit disc.

Comment: Well, that's not the Klein bottle. That's a filled torus.

Comment: @MANI: that is definitely false. It’s the wrong dimension, it has a boundary, and it has the wrong fundamental group.

Comment: @Arthur ok sir, I am seeing it wait please.